# Why does viewport width not match the actual display width?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome shows that my viewport width is 1280px. However, my actual display resolution is 2560x1600px. The machine I use is a 13.3 inch macbook pro. Why the viewport isn't 2560px wide? Using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` doesn't make any difference.

my display settings:
[image]
[image]

Actually, it's not only Chrome, Safari shows the same thing.

Comment: Does your browser window cover the complete screen width?

Comment: yes, it's in fullscreen mode.

Comment: My best guess is that the operating system is tricking the actual pixel size in Chrome? This could be to do with its display settings; tricks like that are common for very high-resolution displays on small screens.

Comment: Meta viewport is only for mobile and tablets, it doesn't work on desktop browsers. Did you changed zoom factor(CTRL+/-). Zooming affects viewport width. And also what properties do you use to get the actual width of the viewport ?

Comment: @BlagoEres: Zoom is set to 100%. I switched the browser to fullscreen mode, selected `html` in the inspector and checked the size according to the box model. Content area is wide 1280px, there is no padding, border or margin.

Answer (score 2):

The viewport for the browser is sized in "CSS pixels", that are not "screen pixels". The difference come from the "display density". In your case you have a "2x" display density, so each CSS pixel is a square of "2x2" screen pixels.

Just render a 10px size div in a page, take a snapshot and check it in your favorite bitmap image editing software: You'll find it's 20 pixels big... I mean 20 SCREEN pixels.

Some more about css pixels and display density:

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Try "css pixels display density" on a search engine and enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to display settings of macbook pro. The default settings of 13.3 inch mbp is 1440x900. so the screen.width=1440 and the screen.height=900. If you adjust the default settings, screen.width and screen.height also changed

Display settings
[image: Display settings]

Get width and height using chrome console
[image: Get width and height using chrome console]

note: using the EasyRes get current display settings